# Trying to understand a proof for the automorphisms of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Consider the following proof for finding all automorphisms of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which I am trying to understand.

[image: proof][Source](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~clayton/courses/502/502_8.pdf)

I have two question regarding the proof

1) They set $d = \deg(\phi(f(x))$. Why does for all non-constant polynomials $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ apply: $\deg(\phi(f(x))) \geq d$? They argue that it applies because $f(x)$ is a linear combination of multiples of x, I don't understand that, and know linear combinations only in terms of vectors. Can you please explain this in a different way?

2) Knowing that $\deg(\phi(f(x))) \geq d$ applies, they follow that $d = 1$, what I don't understand as well. They take a non-constant $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, which exists because the automorphism is surjective. But why does $\phi(f(x)) = x$ apply for it? And how do they follow $d = 1$ from it?

Comment: Side note: This solution is incomplete. It misses $x \mapsto \pm x + a$ for $a \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I claim that the set of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are the ring homomorphisms $\phi$ that satisfy $\phi(x) = \phi_0+\phi_1 x$ where $\phi_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is arbitrary and $\phi_1 \in \{\pm 1\}$.

Suppose $\phi$ is an automorphism. As above, we have $\phi(n) = n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $\phi$ is an automorphism, we can find an inverse for $x$.
Then for some $p_k$ we have $\phi(\sum_{k=0}^n p_k x^k) = x$ (with $p_n \neq 0$). That is, $\sum_{k=0}^n p_k \phi(x)^k = x$. It follows that we must have $\partial \phi(x) \ge 1$, and since $p_n \neq 0$, we must have $\partial \phi(x) = 1$ (and
also, $n=1$).

Hence $\phi(x)$ has the form $\phi(x) = \phi_0+\phi_1 x$ which
gives $p_0 + p_1 \phi_0 + p_1 \phi_1 x = x$. Then $p_1 = \phi_1 \in \{\pm 1\}$
(and $p_0+p_1 \phi_0 = 0$ which gives $p_0 = -p_1 \phi_0 = - \phi_0 \phi_1$).

Now for the other direction.
Suppose $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism and $\phi(x) = \phi_0+\phi_1 x$, where $ \phi_1 \in \{\pm 1\}$.
(Since $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism we have
$\phi(n) = n$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.)
We need to show that $\phi$ has an inverse. By explicit computation, we have $\phi(\phi_1^{-1}( x-\phi_0)) = x$.
Pick some element $\sum_k a_k x^k \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and note that
$\phi ( \sum_k a_k (\phi_1^{-1}( x-\phi_0))^k) = \sum_k a_k x^k$, hence $\phi$ is invertible and so is an automorphism.

Comment: thank you for the answer! Two questions: 1) How do you follow $\phi((- \phi_0 \phi_1 + \phi_1 x)^k) = x^k \Rightarrow \phi$ is an isomorphism, why does this apply? 2) This whole proof does not show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism, does it? This needed to be shown separately for the proof to be complete, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated the answer a little, hopefully this addresses 1). I'm not sure what you mean by 2). If $\phi$ is an automorphism, then it must be  homomorphism.  The above shows that the automorphisms are exactly the homomorphisms satisfying a given property.

Comment: great, now I got it, thank you!

Comment: I went through your proof and still don't understand one thing: You say "Suppose $\phi$ is an automorphism [..]" and show that if this applies, it must be of the form you expected. Then you suppose it is a ring homomorphism, and show that it is has an inverse, and is therefore an automorphism. But isn't left to show that it is a homomorphism? And doesn't the fact that it is bijective only imply it is an isomorphism, and we would need to show that it maps from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? I just want to understand if this covers everything.

Comment: Well, I want to show that the automorphisms are exactly the ring homomorphisms that satisfy the condition. The first part shows that any automorphism satisfies the condition (and is trivially a ring homomorphism). The second part shows that any ring homomorphism that satisfies the condition is an automorphism. Hence these are **exactly** the automorphisms. (An automorphism is an isomorphism from the set into itself).

Comment: I think I may be missing the point of your question. When I write 'suppose $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism', I mean a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]$. I left out many details to reduce an already cluttered answer. Feel free to as for more clarity and I will do my best to answer.

Comment: There is only one thing left. I tried to proof that $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism, which was assumed, but not proven, right? $\phi(1) = 1$, so I need to show that $\phi\left(\sum_{i=0}^n p_i x^i\right) + \phi\left(\sum_{j=0}^m p_j x^j\right) = \phi\left(\sum_{i=0}^n p_i x^i + \sum_{j=0}^m p_j x^j\right)$ and the same for the multiplication. But how can I resolve e.g. $\phi\left(\sum_{i=0}^n p_i x^i\right)$ without using the homomorphism properties, with only using $\phi(n) = n$ and $\phi(x) = \phi_0 + \phi_1 x$?

Comment: Well, you can't. If $\phi$ is not a homomorphism it cannot be an automorphism. Maybe it would help to reword the statement that $\phi$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ **iff** $\phi$ is a map from $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that satisfies the ring homomorphism axioms and $\phi(x) = \phi_0+\phi_1 x$ where $\phi_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\phi_1 \in \{\pm1 \}$.

Comment: @copper.hat: I think you made a mistake typing the inverse element: Note that if $\phi(x) = \phi_0 + \phi_1 x$ then $\phi^{-1}(x) = -\phi_1^{-1} \phi_0 + \phi_1^{-1} x$. In your post the $\cdot^{-1}$ is missing.

Comment: @el_tenedor: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @copper.hat: You're welcome. The same correction applies to the last line of your post: $\phi ( \sum_k a_k (- \phi_0 \phi_1 + \phi_1 x)^k) = \sum_k a_k x^k$ should read $\phi ( \sum_k a_k (\phi_1^{-1} (x - \phi_0))^k) = \sum_k a_k x^k$.

Comment: @el_tenedor: Et iterum, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$, $a_n\ne0$, $n\ge1$, then $\phi(f(x))=a_0+a_1\phi(x)+\cdots+a_n\phi(x)^n$ (note that $a_i\in\mathbb Z$ and then $\phi(a_i)=a_i$) which has the degree equal to $\deg\phi(x)^n=dn\ge d$. Moreover, if $d\ge2$ then $\deg\phi(f(x))=dn\ge2n\ge 2$, so the image of $\phi$ consists of constants and of polynomials of degree $\ge 2$. This shows that the image of $\phi$ is different from $\mathbb Z[x]$, contradicting the surjectivity of $\phi$.

Then $d=1$ and thus $\phi(x)=bx+a$. (Here is where the notes err.) Since $\phi$ is surjective there is $f\in\mathbb Z[x]$ such that $\phi(f(x))=x$ and from $\deg\phi(f(x))=1$ we get $\deg f=1$, so $f(x)=a_0+a_1x$. From $\phi(f(x))=x$ we get $a_0+a_1(bx+a)=x$, hence $a_1b=1$, so $b=\pm1$. Thus you showed that the ring automorphisms of $\mathbb Z[x]$ have the form $\phi(x)=\pm x+a$. (Well, now you have to prove that these are indeed automorphisms, but this is easy enough.)